# XML manipulation in batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have an XML file which should be well formatted by adding comments for items which are in  non XML tags. The sample input file is given below.

```
comment 1
<book id=1>
    Book 1
</book>

comment 2
<book id=2>
    Book 2
</book>

comment 3
<book id=3>
    Book 3
</book>
```

The expected output

```
<!-- comment 1 -->
<book id=1>
    Book 1
</book>

<!-- comment 2 -->
<book id=2>
    Book 2
</book>

<!-- comment 3 -->
<book id=3>
    Book 3
</book>
```

The written batch script.

```
@ECHO off
SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion

SET INTEXTFILE=test.xml
SET OUTTEXTFILE=out.xml

SET "SEARCH_TEXT_1=^<book "
SET "REPLACE_TEXT_1=--^> ^<book "

SET "SEARCH_TEXT_2=^</book^>"
SET "REPLACE_TEXT_2=^</book^> ^<^!--"

SET "comment=<^!--- Converted to well formed XML --> <^!--"
ECHO !comment! > %OUTTEXTFILE%

for /f "tokens=1,* delims=¶" %%A in ( '"type %INTEXTFILE%"') do (
    SET string=%%A
    SET modified=!string:%SEARCH_TEXT_1%=%REPLACE_TEXT_1%!
    SET modified=!modified:%SEARCH_TEXT_2%=%REPLACE_TEXT_2%!
    ECHO !modified! >> %OUTTEXTFILE%
)
```

The error:

```
< was unexpected at this time.
```

This is due to the `'!'` in the line     `SET "REPLACE_TEXT_2=^</book^> ^<^!--"`  Is there any special way to escape `'!'` symbol?

Answer (score 0):

You need to quote your `set`s:

```
SET "string=%%A"
SET "modified=!string:%SEARCH_TEXT_1%=%REPLACE_TEXT_1%!"
SET "modified=!modified:%SEARCH_TEXT_2%=%REPLACE_TEXT_2%!"
```

Otherwise there will be unquoted and unescaped `>` and `<` in the source which are interpreted as redirection, which you don't want.

The result doesn't look quite right yet, though:

```
<!--- Converted to well formed XML --> <!-- 
comment 1--
<book id=1>--
    Book 1--
</book>--
...
```

Also, is there any reason why you're using `delims=¶`? Are you honestly expecting a `¶` character in your input? Or is that just to not use delimiters? In the latter case `delims=` does that.

Comment: delims=¶ is dummy one. Changed to delims=

Answer (score 0):

Your method is not correct because it does not insert the opening comment tag before the first comment (that you patch by explicitly inserting it at beginning), and insert an unclosed opening comment tag at end of file; also, it does not preserve empty lines. The Batch file below correctly enclose any text outside **<book ...> </book>** tags into a comment (successfully tested with your example data):

```
@echo off
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
set bang=!
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set inFile=test.xml
set outFile=out.xml

set "startLine=<book "
set startLen=6
set "endLine=</book>"

echo ^<!bang!--- Converted to well formed XML --^> > %outFile%

set inBook=
(for /F "tokens=1* delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /N "^" %inFile%') do (
   set string=
   set "string=%%b"
   if not defined string (
      echo/
   ) else (
      if "!string:~0,%startLen%!" equ "%startLine%" (
         set inBook=true
      )
      if not defined inBook (
         echo ^<!bang!-- !string! --^>
      ) else (
         echo !string!
         if "!string!" equ "%endLine%" (
            set inBook=
         )
      )
   )
)) >>  %outFile%
```

Antonio